# error: 80070057 The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Tags: c#, visual-c++, com

I have a requirement where I need to get a result out of a C++ Unmanaged dll's method from C#. I am trying to create an instance to the class type and then try to invoke the method using

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

The unmanaged dll is a COM DLL, I can't modify that, I have to just use it. Also I don't have an interop to that COM DLL, I am not sure whether I need to have one or ask someone to create it. Following is the sample declaration present there

Following is the IDL:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XX-XXXXXXXX),
    dual,
    helpstring("IMyClass Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IMyClass : IDispatch
{
    ....
    id(100), helpstring("My Help String")]
    HRESULT MethodToInvoke([out, retval] unsigned short *pVal);
    ....
}

library MyLib
{
importlib("stdole32.tlb");
importlib("stdole2.tlb");
[
    uuid(XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX),
    helpstring("MyClass")
]
coclass MyClass
{
    [default] interface IMyClass;
};
```

Following is the class declaration:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyClass : 
public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
public CComCoClass<CMyClass, &CLSID_MyClass>,
public IDispatchImpl<IMyClass, &IID_IMyClass, &LIBID_MyLib>
{
    STDMETHOD(MethodToInvoke)(WORD *pVal);
}
```

In order to invoke the above `MethodToInvode` I am trying the following code from a C# application:

```
 Type mytype = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyProgID.MyClass");
 object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(mytype);
 result = Convert.ToString(mytype .GetType().InvokeMember("MethodToInvoke", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, null));
```

I am getting following Exception on the line `object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(mytype);`

Exception:

`Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {XXXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXX} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80070057 The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)).`

Please let me know whether what I am trying is achievable, if it is achievable, what all I should verify to make sure mine works. Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you try and `new` it up directly (not using `Activator.CreateInstance`)?

Comment: I am not sure whether I can do a <code>= new mytype</code>, since I won't have the type known to my C# project to pass the compilation. Is there any way to do that actually?

Comment: It is a pretty unusual way for the object factory to fail.  Particularly since it doesn't take any arguments.  Nothing to do with your code, it did not get to do anything useful yet, this goes wrong inside the C++ code.  It is trying to tell you something important, but the error code is too generic to have any real clue what that might be.  You'll have to debug it, or ask the author of that code to help you.